# pdf.js cannot find pdf.worker.js after upgrading to version 1.9.426

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pdf.js

The previous version we used was 1.1.114 and our setup was working just fine.
We put pdf.js and pdf.worker.js under the same directory(Scripts/Libs/Common) and on our main.js, we defined the path for PDFJS.workerSrc.

We decided to upgrade to v1.9.426 because some issues we've had are already fixed but here is the problem: [error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnceE.png)

This error occurs because pdf.js cannot find pdf.worker.js.
Currently, my workaround for this is to update the paths on pdf.js and pdf.worker.js to the directories where we put these two files.
These are the parts I've updated:

```
if (typeof requirejs !== 'undefined' && requirejs.toUrl) {
   workerSrc = requirejs.toUrl('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js');
}
var dynamicLoaderSupported = typeof requirejs !== 'undefined' && 
requirejs.load;
fakeWorkerFilesLoader = useRequireEnsure ? function (callback) {
    require.ensure([], function () {
    var worker;
    worker = require('./pdf.worker.js');
    callback(worker.WorkerMessageHandler);
});
} : dynamicLoaderSupported ? function (callback) {
    requirejs(['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker'], function (worker) {
    callback(worker.WorkerMessageHandler);
});
} : null;
```

---

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker", [], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker"] = factory();
    else
        root["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker"] = 
        root.pdfjsDistBuildPdfWorker = 
        factory();
})
```

Why are the paths on the new version hardcoded? 
How should I properly address this issue?